# Как вытащить в ListView картинку из SQLite, которая там сохранена в виде "название", а сама лежит в drawable или assets

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, изображения

В бд сохранено название картинки (по типу "firstimage") (которые лежат в папке drawable и в assets), получаю курсор

```
 public Cursor getListNameWithImage(String nameTables)
{
    Cursor cursor = null;

    try {
        cursor = this.database.query(nameTables,
                new String[]{"_id", "name", "image"},
                null, null, null, null, null);
    } catch(SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return cursor;

}
```

Вопрос, как вытащить в ListView (xml представление обычное, одно с listview, второе с его содержимым - тестом и картинкой) картинку из бд, имея лишь ее название.

Пробовал получать картинку

```
String name = c.getString("name_img");
int i = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name + ".jpg", "drawable", "ru.example.project");
view.setImageResource(i);

 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open(cursor.getString(2)));
 iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Не получается. Либо грузится без картинок и с ошибками, что файл не найден, либо вообще приложение крашится.

Comment: Так вроде ж только PNG можно же в drawable хранить...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: в drawable хранится .jpg и достается оттуда с помощью рекурсии без особых проблем по имени файла. Однако вопрос состоит в том, как добавить это дело в адаптер. какой метод переопределить и что там сделать, вот в чем вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен. 
Нужно для адаптера переопределить метод

public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex)

и обязательно проверять на соответствие

```
        if(view.getId() == R.id.myicon) {
```

а тут с помощью рефлекшен получить картинку из drawable

Answer (score 2):

Если вы храните файл в папке `drawable`, то лучше всего хранить ее `ID` ресурса, а не путь к файлу. Как пример `R.drawable.first_image = 0x7f050016` - это и должно храниться в базе.

Из ассетс забирать вот так

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(strName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: а если изображений 2 тысячи и они получаются на стадии формирования бд, а не в ходе работы приложения? Поэтому вопрос по факту - в бд лежат названия картинок, которые можно положить или в drawable или в assets. Нужно как-то их оттуда достать и добавить в listview.